# PHP Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I am working with laravel 5.4. The controller function that using laravel run in browser is working. Same function I called via scheduler it returns error.

Note: Soapclient is enabled in my server.
In Controller code:

```
use SoapClient;
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(  
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                'trace' => true, //to debug 
            ));
```

and in kernel.php

```
$schedule->command('eld:fetch')
  ->everyMinute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in laravel 5.4** means that the `SoapClient` class does not been enabled in your server. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Check first if it's enabled with `phpinfo()` function and look in the array if `SoapClient` is mentioned enabled. If it's not enabled, follow the second step.
2. Uncomment the `extension=php_soap.dll` line by removing the semicolon at the beginning, in `php.ini` file.
3. The next step is to restart your server.
4. Now return again to the first step to see if `SoapClient` is now enabled.
5. At this step, you can now import your class like this:

`use SoapClient;
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 'trace' => true));`

Comment: SoapClient is enabled.And i checked via phpinfo().

Comment: Could you locate the _line number_ of this error? **PHP Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in laravel 5.4**. Is it at the import line (`use`) or at the instance creation line (`new`)?

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'SoapClient' not found. Error is created when calling a controller function from the console command.                                                  
        public function handle()
       {

        $orbcomm = new Orbcomm();
        $orbcomm->fetchorbcommdata();

    }